# How to create a Look&Feel aware TableCellRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, tablecellrenderer, uimanager

All the examples I can find of custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)s all seem extend [DefaultTableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html). Nothing wrong with that, I guess, except that you do not get to extend the `TableCellRenderer` functionality of whatever is the current Look&Feel. This is bad. Your `TableCellRenderer` is then not L&F aware.

That is in fact exactly what I want to do: I want to create a custom `TableCellRenderer` that is L&F aware, so rather than extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` it should extend (or decorate) whatever is the `TableCellRenderer` which the L&F has installed by default for the given class type.

I can get to that by doing [myJTable.getDefaultRenderer(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getDefaultRenderer-java.lang.Class-)  but that will not give me a new instance of that class, it will simply return the L&F's 'master' table cell renderer to be used for that type of class. I started out with a solution that created a custom TableCellRenderer that wrapped the instance that I got from the mentioned method (effectively using a Decorator pattern) until I realized that I didn't have my own private instance of a renderer. If I mess with that instance of renderer I cannot do column-specific rendering as any change I do on that instance will affect more columns than intended.

So I've concluded that what I need to do is to create a completely new instance of the L&F's `TableCellRenderer` for that class-type. (in my case class type = `Object`).  I  believe I can get to the relevant class name from somewhere in `UIManager`, but I wouldn't know which key to use. Secondly then - unfortunately - I believe I would have to use Reflection to actually instantiate an object of that TableCellRenderer class.

Are my assumptions correct, i.e. there's unfortunately no factory for TableCellRenderers?  and how would I actually instantiate a new instance of my current L&F's `TableCellRenderer` for class-type `Object` ?  (I know how to use Reflection, if that's the only way)

### UPDATE

As you may have guessed I'm testing with a proprietary L&F as well as the standard ones. This particulary proprietary L&F installs its own TableCellRenderers which is perfectly legal, IMO. The Java Synth L&F does the same. So I don't want to make this a question of a particular L&F.

Test: I create a table with two `String` columns. I install my own custom cell renderer on one of the columns, but not the other. My custom renderer looks like this:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
              JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
              int row, int column) {
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
}
```

As you can see the custom renderer does nothing. Since it does nothing I should get the same rendering effect on both table columns. I don't!  The reason is of course that by simply extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` I'll not 'inherit' the L&F's own TableCellRenderers should it have one/some. On many, many L&F's the above test will in fact render the two columns the same way, but that's more by chance. I want to do things the right way. The fact that extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` produces expected results with most L&Fs is not enough for me. :-)

Comment: *"except that you do not get to extend the TableCellRenderer functionality of whatever is the current Look&Feel. This is bad"* What makes you say that?  The font, the foreground and background colors are based on the `JTable` properties, which are based on the look and feel...

Comment: Sure, but L&F's still install their own `TableCellRenderer`s and they do that for a reason .. I guess.

Comment: Example: Everything based off the Synth Look&Feel use their own `TableCellRenderer`s.

Comment: So?  They are look and feel delegates, the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` doesn't change, what changes is the look and feel delegate. Unless you are intending to design your own look and feel, you shouldn't care...

Comment: 1. TableCellRenderer by default ignoring part of keys from L&F, but can to override (quite almost) all key for all standard L&Fs, 2. no idea whats real goal, expect from, missing those hint in question, comments, answer here, 3. question is about description, but ..., last block of sentences doesn't make me sence, whats factory, XxxRenderer is painting factory, creates an illusion

Comment: @mKorbel. I've updated my question slightly. By factory I meant 'instance factory', which I use as a general Java pattern term, not specific to Swing. I was hoping to find an object factory for TableCellRenderers somewhere in Swing, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this Problem in like this:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer  implements TableCellRenderer {
    //Use appropriate class here
    private final TableCellRenderer defaultTableCellRenderer= new JTable().getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
              JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
              int row, int column) {
        Component c = defaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        // do custom stuff to c here ...
        return c;
    }
}
```

If you don't create a new Instance for the TableCellRenderer you get funky effects, because you change the tables default instance.

Comment: Ahh. Clever. Create a whole new JTable object simply for the purpose of stealing its installed cell renderers. Now, why didn't I think of that ??

Comment: I believe this should be the text book example of creating a custom table cell renderer, rather than the ones from Oracle's [Java Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) where they propose that a custom renderer should simply extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. Sure. That will work ... most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

> Are my assumptions correct, i.e. there's unfortunately no factory for
>   TableCellRenderers? and how would I actually instantiate a new
>   instance of my current L&F's TableCellRenderer for class-type Object ?
>   (I know how to use Reflection, if that's the only way)

I would say your assumptions are off, for example, the following screen shots use the exact same code for Cross platform/metal, System/MacOS and Nimbus (Synth).

[image: Meta/CrossPlatform][image: System/MacOS][image: Nimbus]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test101();
    }

    public Test101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
//                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
//                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    model.addColumn(Character.toString((char)('A' + index)));
                }

                for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
                    Vector rowData = new Vector(10);
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        rowData.add(row + "x" + col);
                    }
                    model.addRow(rowData);
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
                table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
                // Just so you don't tell me that the lookup doens't work
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If you extend from `AbstractTableCellRenderer` or `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, you should be using either the `JTable` and it's properties (font, color etc) or the `UIManager` properties if `JTable` doesn't provide you the information you need.

> So I've concluded that what I need to do is to create a completely new
>   instance of the L&F's TableCellRenderer for that class-type. (in my
>   case class type = Object). I believe I can get to the relevant class
>   name from somewhere in UIManager, but I wouldn't know which key to
>   use. Secondly then - unfortunately - I believe I would have to use
>   Reflection to actually instantiate an object of that TableCellRenderer
>   class.

You would only need to do this if you were actually intending to create your own look and feel.  On a everyday basis providing your own `TableCellRenderer`, which is configured from the properties of the supplied `JTable` and on a few rare occasions, modifying the properties present in the `UIManager` should suffice...

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer. You clearly know your stuff. Unfortunately for some L&F a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` cannot derive everything from table properties. Some L&F's allow you to customize the cell rendering painting itself. I'll miss that when simply extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer`.

Comment: Then the problem isn't the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` the problem is the look and feel.  Generally speaking, the only aspects of renderer you can affect are the unselected colors, the selected colors and the font.

Comment: Don't think that's true. A TableCellRenderer can override lots of things besides what you mention. It can for example paint icons in cells or whatever. It can even do low-level stuff like overriding actual `paint()` method. The possibilities are endless .. and legal.

Comment: Since TableCellRenderer is an interface, technically it can't do anything ;). If you are ignoring the UIManager properties then that's not an issue with the look and feel but your implementation of TableCellRenderer. If you want to make a compatible, cross platform cell renderer, you should be paying attention to the the UIManager.  When getTableCellComponent is called, you need to obtain the information you need to honour the current look and feel settings. The DefaultTableCellRenderer does a very good job at all of this...